# Changing state in array state redux react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

The inital state I have for result list from server will be on `result`

```
var InitialState = Record({
   result:[]
})
```

The result from server is list of search result.

Example array result

```
[{id:1 ,Bookmark:true},
{id:2 ,Bookmark:true}],
.....
```

My reducer

```
case SET_BOOKMARK:
      return state.setIn(['result', 'Bookmark'], action.payload.total)
```

I want to update the specific bookmark state when user bookmark specific id, How to achive that? How to reducer look like?

Comment: What is wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: The problem I dont know how to set my reducer, since its array, lets say I want to update id 2 bookmark How state.setIn(['result', 'Bookmark'], action.payload.total) should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for your case

```
const { setIn } = require('immutable@4.0.0-rc.9')

const state = {"results": [{id:1 ,Bookmark:true},
{id:2 ,Bookmark:true}]};

function findElementIndex(arr, key, value) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i][key] === value)
      return i;
}
const newState = setIn(state, 
    ['results', findElementIndex(state.results, 'id', 1), 'Bookmark'], false);

console.log(newState);
```